# Can't put bootstrap Icon into web.css file

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-icons

I am trying to add a bootstrap icon at the end of all my dropbtns, so I wanted to do that in my css file.  I am able to add their icons directly in the web page like
<i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i> but I have been unable to get it to work in web.css.  All it does is add an empty box like it cannot find the icon.

They say the css for it is \F282 (https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-down/)

html

<button onclick="toggleDropDown(this)" class="dropbtn">Please select a field</button>

web.css

```
.dropbtn::after{
    content: "\F282";
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer for me-

Found it. I had to add the font-family

```
.dropbtn::after{
        content: "\f282";
        justify-content: flex-end;
        font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.  I had to add the font-family

```
.dropbtn::after{
        content: "\f282";
        justify-content: flex-end;
        font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Odd this is not mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you using bootstrap icon you should add import link to your css file.

For example at start of your web.css file you should add bootstrap icon

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
```

If you cant use that way you can use this link for your html head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstraicons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

My advice using direct svg link to your html file is more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but I had just found the answer.

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy method for you.

Every class you add will be ready to define bootstrap icon.

```css
    .bi{
       display: inline-block;
       font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
       font-size: inherit;
       text-rendering: auto;
    }

    dropbtn::after{
        content: "\f282";
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleDropDown(this)" class="bi dropbtn">Please select a field</button>
```